# How to hide "Notifications" tab for a user or group from the Account admin page?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

How to hide "**Notifications**" tab for a user or group from the Account admin page in Wagtail?

I see a lot of documentation on how to add my own tab but I want to hide "Notifications" tab completely

Ideally, an existing hook to edit panels list of the logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like there isn't an existing hook for removing a panel from the account form but the panel itself has an `is_active` method. Try overriding https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/43c1753cb5b411129d032b9b2c136f691140555b/wagtail/admin/views/account.py#L155 to make `is_active` return false.